# ggplot2 and RcolorBrewer with qualitative palettes of 2 values

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I used RColorBrewer to set the colors in ggplot2. I wrote a function and on the same chart I superimpose from 1 to 4 lines. In order to set a color I use:

```
scale_color_brewer(type="qual", palette="Set1")
```

According to manual "for qualitative palettes, the lowest number of distinct values available always is 3" therefore when the number of lines equal to 1 or 2, I get warning messages. Is there any claver trick to cope with?

Robert

@Ben Bolker: You are absolutely right that a reproducible example in many cases has to be submit although here is not necessary. Because my original function is long I prepared simple example showing the problem.

```
library("datasets")
library("ggplot2")

set.seed(1367)
y <- log10(lynx)
y.estim <- y + rnorm(length(y), sd=0.2)
mydf <- data.frame(time=1:length(y), y, y.estim) 
mydf <- melt(mydf, id="time")

p <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x=time, y=value, color=variable))
p + geom_line() + geom_point(size=2) + theme_bw() +
   scale_color_brewer(type="qual", palette="Set1") #here is a problem
```

Maybe I could specify color directly. I know that

```
library("RColorBrewer")
> brewer.pal(4, "Set1")
[1] "#E41A1C" "#377EB8" "#4DAF4A" "#984EA3"
```

Is it possible to work with e.g. "#E41A1C" ?

Comment: I tried before posting - it's not work.

Comment: supressWarnings will only work if you are wrapping an explicit call to `print`, which when `brewer.pal` appears to be evaluated.

Comment: @user1160354: just a couple of quick thoughts about posting -- (1) a reproducible example is nice (although in this case not *totally* necessary perhaps since the question is simple and clear); (2) it helps to say what you've already tried (e.g. "I've already tried `suppressWarnings()` and still got the warnings"), just to save others time ..

Comment: if `suppressWarnings` doesn't work, maybe you could try `old_opt <- options(warn=-1); ggplot(...); options(old_opt)`

Comment: @Ben: It works but every time I call my function I have to use options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @mnel suggests, wrapping the statement in an explicit `print` statement appears to work:

```
suppressWarnings(print(p + geom_line() + geom_point(size=2) + theme_bw() +
     scale_color_brewer(type="qual", palette="Set1")))
```

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R Under development (unstable) (2012-10-14 r60940)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

[snip]

other attached packages:
[1] reshape2_1.2.1  ggplot2_0.9.2.1
```

---

Edit - @mnel

You can redefine `print.ggplot` to automatically do this. I don't know whether this will cause 
environment (`parent.frame` issues)

```
print.ggplot <- function(..., warnings = getOption('ggplot_warning', default = TRUE)){
  if(warnings){
    ggplot2:::print.ggplot(...))} else { 
     suppressWarnings(ggplot2:::print.ggplot(...))
   }
  }
```

So, if you want to have all the warnings for a ggplot printing set to off, you just set

```
options(ggplot_warning = FALSE)
```

Otherwise it should act as normal.

Comment: thank you for details, because I didn't understand how to use print. Now it works fine.

Comment: Instead of use scale_color_brewer(type="qual", palette="Set1") one can use:
  
 `mycol <- brewer.pal(4, "Set1");
 scale_color_manual(values = mycol)`

Comment: @Ben Bolker, have added a `print` method to implement, feel free to remove if you think it unwise.